# What are "Write Only (Drop Box)" permissions?

Tags: permission

I noticed under Sharing & Permission in folder/file info that I have a weird third type of permissions. Next to Read & Write and Read Only, I also have the option "Write Only (Drop Box)".

I was hence wondering what these permissions are. Are they related to the Dropbox app?

[image: Screenshot of folder Info]

Comment: From [macOS Sierra: Set permissions for items on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25287), "Write Only: Makes a folder into a drop box. Users can copy items to the drop box, but can’t open it. Only the owner of the drop box can open it."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These users may only save files to your dropbox, but cannot read the content (maybee even not see the file itself) of already existing files.

As opposed as to "Read only" where they can only read existing stuff but not save new files.

It has nothing to to with dropbox.com.

This is a OSX/macOS own sharing system